# Binding view table data to MVC model

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am working on an existing project, someone wrote a view and is attempting to bind table data to a model list, It doesn't work and my skills are not up the task of figuring out why

heres the javascript line I assume is supposed to set the binding

```
$("#benefitsTable").bindmvclist();
```

and here is the table inside the view

Benefit Type
                        Amount
                        Expiry Date

```
                @* The insert template is only needed when the form is unlocked and therefore editable. *@
                @if (Model.IsUnlocked)
                {
                    <div data-type="itemtemplate" class="benefits-row">
                        @if (Model.CanEdit)
                        {
                            <input id="Benefits_{0}__AllowanceId" name="Benefits_[{0}].AllowanceID" type="hidden" value="0"/>
                            <select id="Benefits_{0}__AllowanceTypeId" name="Benefits[{0}].AllowanceTypeID" style="width: 220px">
                                @foreach (var allowance in Model.AllowanceTypesBenefits)
                                {
                                    <option value="@allowance.Value">@allowance.Text</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                            <input id="Benefits_{0}__AllowanceAmount" name="Benefits[{0}].Amount" type="text" value="" style="width: 68px;"/>
                            <input id="Benefits_{0}__ExpiryDate" name="Benefits[{0}].ExpiryDate" type="text" value="" class="datepickerrecurring datepicker" style="width: 80px"/>
                            <a class="removeBenefit" href="#"><i class="icon-close-delete"></i></a>
                        }
                        else if (Model.CanView)
                        {
                            <p>@Model.Benefits[0].AllowanceTypeName</p>
                        }
                    </div>
                }
                @if (Model.Benefits != null)
                {
                            @* Do not turn into a foreach. *@
                    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Benefits.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        <div class="benefits-row">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(a => Model.Benefits[i].AllowanceID) @* This somehow magically turns into id="Benefits_0__AllowanceTypeID" name="Benefits[0].AllowanceTypeID", which is why a foreach won't work. *@

                            @if (Model.IsUnlocked)
                            {
                                if (Model.CanEdit)
                                {
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => Model.Benefits[i].AllowanceTypeID, new SelectList(Model.AllowanceTypesBenefits, "Value", "Text", Model.Benefits[i].AllowanceTypeID), new {@style = "width:220px;"}, Model.CanView)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.Benefits[i].Amount, Model.CanView, new {maxlength = "100", size = "8", Value = String.Format("{0:0.00}", Model.Benefits[i].Amount)})
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Benefits[i].Amount)

                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.Benefits[i].ExpiryDate, new {@class = "datepicker", @style = "width: 80px;", Value = String.Format("{0:d/MM/yyyy}", Model.Benefits[i].ExpiryDate), @readonly = "readonly"})
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Benefits[i].ExpiryDate)
                                    <a class="removeBenefit" href="#"><i class="icon-close-delete"></i></a>
                                }
                                else if (Model.CanView)
                                {
                                    <span class="benefitLabel">@Model.Benefits[i].AllowanceTypeName</span>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.Benefits[i].Amount, Model.CanView, new {maxlength = "100", size = "8", Value = String.Format("{0:0.00}", Model.Benefits[i].Amount), @readonly = "readonly", disabled = "disabled"})
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.Benefits[i].ExpiryDate, new {@style = "width: 80px;", Value = String.Format("{0:d/MM/yyyy}", Model.Benefits[i].ExpiryDate), @readonly = "readonly", disabled = "disabled"})
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span class="benefitLabel">@Model.Benefits[i].AllowanceTypeName</span>
                                <input type="text" size="8" value="###" disabled="disabled"/>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.Benefits[i].ExpiryDate, new {@class = "datepicker", @style = "width: 80px;", Value = String.Format("{0:d/MM/yyyy}", Model.Benefits[i].ExpiryDate), @readonly = "readonly", disabled = "disabled"})

                            }
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated :)

NOTE: evertime the page is loaded the console logs the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bindmvclist is not a function"

Comment: What is `bindmvclist()`? And what problems are you having?

Comment: Please see Edits also, I am unsure what `bindmvclist()` is, I think it's a built in JQuery function (I'm using JQuery 2.1.4), the issue is whenever I pass through the model to the controller, this data is always null, even when I eneter values into the inputs

Comment: It not a 'built-in' jquery function. It may be a function of a jquery plugin (but does not sound like it) or a function the original author wrote. Just comment it out and the `Uncaught TypeError` will go away. The conditional statements inside you loop mean that you will not be generating collection indexers that are zero based and consecutive so binding will fail when you submit.

Comment: I'm not quite following you, what's wrong with the conditional statements?

Comment: There are multiple issues with the code inside the `for` statement - you never set the `value` attribute when using html helpers. You set the `disabled` attribute which means the value wont be posted back. But your question was about the `Uncaught TypeError` not about binding

Comment: I thought the uncaught TypeError was causing the binding issue, now I have to sort out the binding issue if that's not the case. The problem is I didn't write this code, the dev before me did, so I'm a little lost

Comment: The `Uncaught TypeError` is because there is no jquery function named `bindmvclist()` - and who knows what that function might have been doing :)

Comment: Ok, would you be able to link me to some articles that could teach me how to bind the data to the model properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94032/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-fraser-jordan).